# error TS2339: Property 'fileReset' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

> Hello evreryone, I am new in Angular an i am trying to import a CSV
>   file with Angular 7, using Typescript 3.2.2 and i am getting errors.
>   Can some one help please?  This is the fisrt solution i am trying

Here my app.components.ts file

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var $;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('dataTable') table;
  dataTable: any;
  dtOption: any = {};
  title = 'Aegon Script Generation';

  constructor(){
  }
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.dtOption = {
          "paging":   false,
          "ordering": true,
          "scrollY":  '50vh',
          "scrollX":  true,
          "info":     false
      };
    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable(this.dtOption);
  }


   /**This method will be used to check if the selected file is a valid CSV file or not */
    isCSVFile(file: any)
    {
       return file.name.endsWith(".csv");
    }

   /**This method will fetch the first row of the CSV file as the headers list for the result and return the list to the calling function.*/
    getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any)
    {
       let headers = csvRecordsArr[0].split(',');
       let headerArray = [];

       for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                   headerArray.push(headers[j]);
       }
      return headerArray;
    }

    /**This method will iterate over each row of CSV file skipping the first row which is the header. On each iteration
       only the rows with columns equal to header numbers will be pushed to the main record.*/
    getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any)
    {
              var dataArr = []

              for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
                   let data = csvRecordsArray[i].split(',');
                   /**FOR EACH ROW IN CSV FILE IF THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS
                   ARE SAME AS NUMBER OF HEADER COLUMNS THEN PARSE THE DATA */

                   if (data.length == headerLength) {
                        var csvRecord: CSVRecord = new CSVRecord();
                        csvRecord.firstName = data[0].trim();
                        csvRecord.lastName = data[1].trim();
                        csvRecord.email = data[2].trim();
                        csvRecord.phoneNumber = data[3].trim();
                        csvRecord.title = data[4].trim();
                        csvRecord.occupation = data[5].trim();
                        dataArr.push(csvRecord);
                   }
               }
        return dataArr;
    }


    /**This method is called on the file selection. It uses FileReader to parse the input CSV file an then makes use
       of the previous 3 methods discussed above to Confirm if the files selected is a CSV file if yes then accordingly
       fetch the Headers and Row data from the file.*/
    fileChangeListener($event: any): void
    {
              var text = [];
              var files = $event.srcElement.files;

              if (this.isCSVFile(files[0])) {
                 var input = $event.target;
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

                 reader.onload = (data) => {
                      let csvData = reader.result;
                      let csvRecordsArray = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                      let headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);
                      this.csvRecords =
                         this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray,
                         headersRow.length);         }

                         reader.onerror = function() {
                             alert('Unable to read' + input.files[0]);
                         };
                } else {
                       alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
                       this.fileReset();
              }
    }


}
```

Here is my errors 
I tried to changee the lib conf into the tsconfig.json

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(62,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CSVRecord'.
src/app/app.component.ts(62,56): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'CSVRecord'. Did you mean 'csvRecord'?
src/app/app.component.ts(91,53): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.
  Property 'split' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.
src/app/app.component.ts(93,28): error TS2339: Property 'csvRecords' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
src/app/app.component.ts(102,29): error TS2339: Property 'fileReset' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

Comment: What is `CSVRecord`? Is it coming from some third party library?

Comment: @PareshLomate to be sincere i cant really give u an answer, i copy the code from a tuto (How to Import CSV file in Angular 7 ( No Library Needed)),  but i thing is like an interface ...

Comment: You're not using the full code from the tutorial. At the end of the [blog post](https://blog.developershive.com/how-to-import-csv-file-in-angular-7-no-library-needed/blog/develkwl/) you probably read there's a link to a github repository with the [complete code](https://github.com/tofiqquadri/Angular-Framework-7-CSV-Import/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts). Try that one.

Comment: @fridoo is correct. Create the interface as mentioned at the bottom of the code. Just remember to change the interface members are per you CSV data.

Comment: @fridoo your right let me look deep into and let you know more about.

Comment: Thks @fridoo i no more get those errors. I now have to deal wikth the split problem:  " ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(101,53): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.
  Property 'split' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'."